# CArtAgO "execLinkedOp failed java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: INTERNAL ERROR: Op Exec Context cannot be restored."

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, agent, multi-agent

I am trying to execute a remote operation, which means, an operation of another CArtAgO artifact. After the execution of the following @LINK operation an exception is occurring:

```
@LINK 
void reply() throws OperationException {
    try {
        log("received keepalive back!");
    }
}
```

CArtAgO is giving the following error message:

> ERROR: (ArtifactC) Error on execLinkedOp without parameters!
>   cartago.OperationException: execLinkedOp failed
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: INTERNAL ERROR: Op Exec Context
>   cannot be restored.   at
>   cartago.Artifact.execLinkedOp(Artifact.java:964)  at
>   camelartifact.CamelArtifact.receiveMsg(CamelArtifact.java:112)    at
>   camelartifact.CamelArtifact.access$200(CamelArtifact.java:48)     at
>   camelartifact.CamelArtifact$ReadCmd.exec(CamelArtifact.java:207)  at
>   cartago.Artifact.await(Artifact.java:831)     at
>   camelartifact.CamelArtifact.listenRoutes(CamelArtifact.java:68)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   cartago.ArtifactOpMethod.exec(ArtifactOpMethod.java:39)   at
>   cartago.Artifact.doOperation(Artifact.java:407)   at
>   cartago.Artifact.access$200(Artifact.java:32)     at
>   cartago.Artifact$ArtifactAdapter.doOperation(Artifact.java:1275)  at
>   cartago.WorkspaceKernel.serveOperation(WorkspaceKernel.java:1136)     at
>   cartago.WorkspaceKernel.access$000(WorkspaceKernel.java:48)   at
>   cartago.WorkspaceKernel$EnvironmentController.run(WorkspaceKernel.java:1477)

What exactly is this error "op exec context cannot be restored" and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This error typically happens when you are calling execLinkedOp without being a CArtAgO internal thread, e.g., directly from some external Java threads, you should use **IBlockingCmd** with **await** methods. You can follow [this](http://cartago.sourceforge.net/?page_id=112) example.

Another recommendations:

- use @LINK annotation on external method (the one that is being remotelly called)
- use @INTERNAL_OPERATION for local methods and execInternalOp() to call them.